# Estimated voltage, amperage and phase count of this MASSIVE busbar system?

Tags: power, busbar

[image]

Any guesses as to the likely voltage, amperage, and phase count running on this massive 3-conductor copper busbar system?

Found in an old factory. Decommissioned long ago, so I can't just poke it with multimeter. :)

[image]

Comment: We had a new factory 20 yrs ago with bigger cable troughs for fibre bundles as big as my thighs.  Sorry just had to throw that in. this is for 3phase AC grid.  and that is normal.

Comment: Can I buy the copper?

Comment: I’ve installed bigger bus bars then that!  :)

Comment: "(it's off and thus) I can't poke it with a multimeter": and that feels somehow like a good thing, because this really looks like it would brighten the room right up should you drop your keyring, watch or screwdriver into one of the unisolated places :)

Comment: I have a wild guess regarding phase count, by the way :D it strongly correlates with the number of bars.

Comment: Also, do you have some size reference? It's a bit hard to guess whether these bars are 5 cm across or 2 cm.

Comment: Anodizing systems use big bus bars, 10,000s amps, 29 volts.

Comment: @MarcusMüller RE phase count, That was my first thought as well, but couldn't it also be two phase with neutral?

Comment: @bigjosh 2L+N: I think that's very rare in such high-powered systems, as that might actually measurably unbalance the grid around the consumer.